# Android mobile as a GSM modem?

Tags: android, .net, gsm, modem

Is it possible to use an Android mobile device as a GSM modem?

I have been working with GSM modems for several years. I am developing apps under .net to make data calls, send/reieve SMSs and so on, i used normal GSM modems so far, not mobiles.

Now I'd like to connect some android devices via USB to my PC and use it as a GSM modem, communicate with it via standard AT commands.

Is there any kind of driver/app/etc to handle it? It would be nice to communicate with it via RS232.

Thanks!

Environment: Windows XP/Windows 7
Mobile to test: Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly don't know a straight answer to your question, but I would recommend perusing the docs on USB to see what data/info you can transfer.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html

With what you're wanting, though, you'd also need to develop your own desktop app. You may be able to use ADB/shell to communicate. Phones may also need to be rooted for it, depending on how much control you want.

Drivers required would be the device manufacturer's USB drivers, if any were needed (which they are for ADB/Shell).

Comment: Thx. So it is not a straightforward thing to use Android mobile as GSM modem. It surprises me a bit, cause e.g. old Nokia models was very easy to use as GSM modem.

Comment: I haven't tried to do it myself, so don't take my word for it, but I am pretty sure that what you're trying to accomplish would be a task and is not directly built into Android.

Answer (score 0):

I have found very helpful what I want in my application. Following android application today I have found and worked for me.

It gives the two APIs through JSON. First for sending SMS and second for receiving SMS in my Server side programming language.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsmmodem

Comment: You should try with two different packages. find the details on following post https://sindhitutorials.com/blog/gsm-modem-free-sms-android-app/